# How do I programmatically get the free disk space for a directory in Linux

Tags: c++, linux

Is there a function that returns how much space is free on a drive partition given a directory path?

Answer (score 107, accepted):

check `man statvfs(2)`

I believe you can calculate 'free space' as  `f_bsize * f_bfree`.

```
NAME
       statvfs, fstatvfs - get file system statistics

SYNOPSIS
       #include <sys/statvfs.h>

       int statvfs(const char *path, struct statvfs *buf);
       int fstatvfs(int fd, struct statvfs *buf);

DESCRIPTION
       The function statvfs() returns information about a mounted file system.
       path is the pathname of any file within the mounted file  system.   buf
       is a pointer to a statvfs structure defined approximately as follows:

           struct statvfs {
               unsigned long  f_bsize;    /* file system block size */
               unsigned long  f_frsize;   /* fragment size */
               fsblkcnt_t     f_blocks;   /* size of fs in f_frsize units */
               fsblkcnt_t     f_bfree;    /* # free blocks */
               fsblkcnt_t     f_bavail;   /* # free blocks for unprivileged users */
               fsfilcnt_t     f_files;    /* # inodes */
               fsfilcnt_t     f_ffree;    /* # free inodes */
               fsfilcnt_t     f_favail;   /* # free inodes for unprivileged users */
               unsigned long  f_fsid;     /* file system ID */
               unsigned long  f_flag;     /* mount flags */
               unsigned long  f_namemax;  /* maximum filename length */
           };
```

Comment: statvfs does not seem to work for vfat mounted drives. I tried it with a FAT 32 partition and its gives 0 for available blocks. Is there a way to work it out?

Comment: @ShadmanAnwer unfortunately the man page says:
`It is unspecified whether all members of the returned struct have meaningful values on all file systems.`  So perhaps FAT32 is not supported in this case.

Comment: Use `f_bsize * f_bavail` to have data consistent to `df -h` command.

Comment: I get huge difference between f_bfree and f_bavail, that's really weird, around 40%. But 'df' as @speed488 says is consistent with f_bavail.

Comment: The difference between f_bfree and f_bavail is due to blocks reserved for the super user (ext2/3/4 file systems). This defaults to 5% of the disk. It can be altered using `tune2fs` with options `-r <count>` or `-m <percentage>`. It can also be set during file system creation.

Answer (score 39):

You can use boost::filesystem:

```
struct space_info  // returned by space function
{
    uintmax_t capacity;
    uintmax_t free; 
    uintmax_t available; // free space available to a non-privileged process
};

space_info   space(const path& p);
space_info   space(const path& p, system::error_code& ec);
```

Example:

```
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>
using namespace boost::filesystem;
space_info si = space(".");
cout << si.available << endl;
```

Returns: An object of type space_info. The value of the space_info object is determined as if by using POSIX statvfs() to obtain a POSIX struct statvfs, and then multiplying its f_blocks, f_bfree, and f_bavail members by its f_frsize member, and assigning the results to the capacity, free, and available members respectively. Any members for which the value cannot be determined shall be set to -1.

Answer (score 27):

## With C++17

You can use [`std::filesystem::space`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/space):

```cpp
#include <iostream>  // only needed for screen output

#include <filesystem>
namespace fs = std::filesystem;

int main()
{
    fs::space_info tmp = fs::space("/tmp");

    std::cout << "Free space: " << tmp.free << '\n'
              << "Available space: " << tmp.available << '\n';
}
```

Comment: This may require a linker addition in your Makefile.  I needed ``-lstdc++fs``.  See notes [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem)

Answer (score 3):

You can use Qt class QStorageInfo to acquire hardisk free space:
First,you should include the header:

```
#include <QStorageInfo> 
#define GB (1024 * 1024 * 1024)
bool CheckHardiskFree(const QString &strDisk)
{
    QStorageInfo storage(strDisk);
    if(storage.isValid() && storage.isReady())
    {
     double useGb =(storage.bytesTotal()-storage.bytesAvailable()) * 1.0/ GB;
     double freeGb =storage.bytesAvailable() * 1.0 / GB;
     double allGb =storage.bytesTotal()* 1.0 / GB;
     return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: for qt users very useful

Comment: But this doesn't work for network mounts.

Answer (score -3):

One can get the output of a command into a program by using a pipe like this:

```
char cmd[]="df -h /path/to/directory" ;
FILE* apipe = popen(cmd, "r");
// if the popen succeeds read the commands output into the program with 
while (  fgets( line, 132 , apipe) )
{  // handle the readed lines
} 
pclose(apipe);
// -----------------------------------
```

Comment: Opening commands spawns new processes, which can be 500x - 2000x slower than that of a C API call. Ultimately the program you are spawning may also be written in C, and you are doing a lot of unnecessary work.