# Get amount of free disk space using Go

Tags: go, diskspace

Basically I want the output of `df -h`, which includes both the free space and the total size of the volume.  The solution needs to work on Windows, Linux, and Mac and be written in Go.

I have looked through the `os` and `syscall` Go documentation and haven't found anything.  On Windows, even command line utils are either awkward (`dir C:\`) or need elevated privileges (`fsutil volume diskfree C:\`). Surely there is a way to do this that I haven't found yet...

UPDATE:
Per nemo's answer and invitation, I have provided a [cross-platform Go package](https://github.com/ricochet2200/go-disk-usage) that does this.

Comment: All I've got is that you could drop to C with [cgo](http://blog.golang.org/c-go-cgo): write freespace_windows.go and freespace_{linux,bsd}.go, and use [GetDiskFreeSpace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364935(v=vs.85).aspx) and [statvfs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3992171/how-do-i-programmatically-get-the-free-disk-space-for-a-directory-in-linux) to get free space.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

On POSIX systems you can use [`sys.unix.Statfs`](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/sys/unix#Statfs).
Example of printing free space in bytes of current working directory:

```
import "golang.org/x/sys/unix"
import "os"

var stat unix.Statfs_t

wd, err := os.Getwd()

unix.Statfs(wd, &stat)

// Available blocks * size per block = available space in bytes
fmt.Println(stat.Bavail * uint64(stat.Bsize))
```

For Windows you need to go the syscall route as well. Example ([source](http://wendal.net/2012/1224.html), updated to match [new `sys/windows` package](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/sys/windows)):

```
import "golang.org/x/sys/windows"

var freeBytesAvailable uint64
var totalNumberOfBytes uint64
var totalNumberOfFreeBytes uint64

err := windows.GetDiskFreeSpaceEx(windows.StringToUTF16Ptr("C:"),
    &freeBytesAvailable, &totalNumberOfBytes, &totalNumberOfFreeBytes)
```

Feel free to write a package that provides the functionality cross-platform.
On how to implement something cross-platform, see the [build tool help page](http://golang.org/pkg/go/build/#hdr-Build_Constraints).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed post.  I have updated my question to include the link to my package that does this.

Comment: Do you know the difference between `stat.Bavail` and `stat.Bfree`? Documented here: https://golang.org/pkg/syscall/#Statfs_t

Comment: @bantl23 `Bavail` is the amount of blocks available to unprivileged users. `Bfree` is simply the total number of free blocks.

Comment: "On POSIX systems you can use syscall.Statfs" Unfortunatly this isn't a POSIX compliant syscall. The POSIX compliant call is "statvfs". Statfs gives different information on different *NIX OS'es. Why the Go makers choose to implement the non-POSIX compliant version is beyond me.

Comment: gives me error: `'wd' unexpected` in line `wd, err := os.Getwd()`

Comment: From the package docs: "Deprecated: this package is locked down. Callers should use the corresponding package in the golang.org/x/sys repository instead. https://golang.org/pkg/syscall/#Statfs

Comment: @BrettHolman quite right, updated the answer

Comment: I think there is a typo in the declaration of freeBytes: int64 should be uint64, no?

Answer (score 11):

Here is my version of the `df -h` command based on [github.com/shirou/gopsutil](https://github.com/shirou/gopsutil/) library

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    human "github.com/dustin/go-humanize"
    "github.com/shirou/gopsutil/disk"
)

func main() {
    formatter := "%-14s %7s %7s %7s %4s %s\n"
    fmt.Printf(formatter, "Filesystem", "Size", "Used", "Avail", "Use%", "Mounted on")

    parts, _ := disk.Partitions(true)
    for _, p := range parts {
        device := p.Mountpoint
        s, _ := disk.Usage(device)

        if s.Total == 0 {
            continue
        }

        percent := fmt.Sprintf("%2.f%%", s.UsedPercent)

        fmt.Printf(formatter,
            s.Fstype,
            human.Bytes(s.Total),
            human.Bytes(s.Used),
            human.Bytes(s.Free),
            percent,
            p.Mountpoint,
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: This works very well on Windows 10 and MacOS 11.3. Thank you.

Answer (score 9):

Minio has a package ([GoDoc](https://godoc.org/github.com/minio/minio/pkg/disk)) to show disk usage that is cross platform, and seems to be well maintained:

```
import (
        "github.com/minio/minio/pkg/disk"
        humanize "github.com/dustin/go-humanize"
)

func printUsage(path string) error {
        di, err := disk.GetInfo(path)
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }
        percentage := (float64(di.Total-di.Free)/float64(di.Total))*100
        fmt.Printf("%s of %s disk space used (%0.2f%%)\n", 
            humanize.Bytes(di.Total-di.Free), 
            humanize.Bytes(di.Total), 
            percentage,
        )
}
```

Comment: This code is actually provides data from output of `du -h` e.g. directory usage instead of requested `df -h` command providing a disk usage. Anyway It may be a good example of using minio package.

Comment: go: module github.com/minio/minio@upgrade found (v0.0.0-20230424202818-8fd07bcd51cf), but does not contain package github.com/minio/minio/pkg/disk

Comment: The package is now github.com/minio/minio/internal/disk and cannot be used.