# Add and generate custom system calls in golang

Tags: windows, go, wmi, monitoring, system-calls

I want to add the system call `GetDiskFreeSpaceExW` to the go systemcalls and extend the currently available syscalls for hcsshim: https://github.com/microsoft/hcsshim/blob/master/zsyscall_windows.go

I saw that there is a way of generating them, but it is still unclear how the syntax will be for adding another DLL and what struct types have to be used.

The current **hcs.go** which is used to generate the system calls for hcsshim:

```
// Shim for the Host Compute Service (HCS) to manage Windows Server
// containers and Hyper-V containers.

package hcs

import (
    "syscall"
)

//go:generate go run ../../mksyscall_windows.go -output zsyscall_windows.go hcs.go

//sys hcsEnumerateComputeSystems(query string, computeSystems **uint16, result **uint16) (hr error) = vmcompute.HcsEnumerateComputeSystems?
//sys hcsCreateComputeSystem(id string, configuration string, identity syscall.Handle, computeSystem *hcsSystem, result **uint16) (hr error) = vmcompute.HcsCreateComputeSystem?
//sys hcsOpenComputeSystem(id string, computeSystem *hcsSystem, result **uint16) (hr error) = vmcompute.HcsOpenComputeSystem?
//sys hcsCloseComputeSystem(computeSystem hcsSystem) (hr error) = vmcompute.HcsCloseComputeSystem?
//sys hcsStartComputeSystem(computeSystem hcsSystem, options string, result **uint16) (hr error) = vmcompute.HcsStartComputeSystem?
//sys hcsShutdownComputeSystem(computeSystem hcsSystem, options string, result **uint16) (hr error) = vmcompute.HcsShutdownComputeSystem?
//sys hcsTerminateComputeSystem(computeSystem hcsSystem, options string, result **uint16) (hr error) = vmcompute.HcsTerminateComputeSystem?
//sys hcsPauseComputeSystem(computeSystem hcsSystem, options string, result **uint16) (hr error) = vmcompute.HcsPauseComputeSystem?
//sys hcsResumeComputeSystem(computeSystem hcsSystem, options string, result **uint16) (hr error) = vmcompute.HcsResumeComputeSystem?
//sys hcsGetComputeSystemProperties(computeSystem hcsSystem, propertyQuery string, properties **uint16, result **uint16) (hr error) = vmcompute.HcsGetComputeSystemProperties?
//sys hcsModifyComputeSystem(computeSystem hcsSystem, configuration string, result **uint16) (hr error) = vmcompute.HcsModifyComputeSystem?
//sys hcsRegisterComputeSystemCallback(computeSystem hcsSystem, callback uintptr, context uintptr, callbackHandle *hcsCallback) (hr error) = vmcompute.HcsRegisterComputeSystemCallback?
//sys hcsUnregisterComputeSystemCallback(callbackHandle hcsCallback) (hr error) = vmcompute.HcsUnregisterComputeSystemCallback?

//sys hcsCreateProcess(computeSystem hcsSystem, processParameters string, processInformation *hcsProcessInformation, process *hcsProcess, result **uint16) (hr error) = vmcompute.HcsCreateProcess?
//sys hcsOpenProcess(computeSystem hcsSystem, pid uint32, process *hcsProcess, result **uint16) (hr error) = vmcompute.HcsOpenProcess?
//sys hcsCloseProcess(process hcsProcess) (hr error) = vmcompute.HcsCloseProcess?
//sys hcsTerminateProcess(process hcsProcess, result **uint16) (hr error) = vmcompute.HcsTerminateProcess?
//sys hcsSignalProcess(process hcsProcess, options string, result **uint16) (hr error) = vmcompute.HcsSignalProcess?
//sys hcsGetProcessInfo(process hcsProcess, processInformation *hcsProcessInformation, result **uint16) (hr error) = vmcompute.HcsGetProcessInfo?
//sys hcsGetProcessProperties(process hcsProcess, processProperties **uint16, result **uint16) (hr error) = vmcompute.HcsGetProcessProperties?
//sys hcsModifyProcess(process hcsProcess, settings string, result **uint16) (hr error) = vmcompute.HcsModifyProcess?
//sys hcsGetServiceProperties(propertyQuery string, properties **uint16, result **uint16) (hr error) = vmcompute.HcsGetServiceProperties?
//sys hcsRegisterProcessCallback(process hcsProcess, callback uintptr, context uintptr, callbackHandle *hcsCallback) (hr error) = vmcompute.HcsRegisterProcessCallback?
//sys hcsUnregisterProcessCallback(callbackHandle hcsCallback) (hr error) = vmcompute.HcsUnregisterProcessCallback?

//sys hcsGetDiskFreeSpaceExW(string lpDirectoryName, **uint16 lpFreeBytesAvailableToCaller, **uint16 lpTotalNumberOfBytes, **uint16 lpTotalNumberOfFreeBytes) = 

type hcsSystem syscall.Handle
type hcsProcess syscall.Handle
type hcsCallback syscall.Handle

type hcsProcessInformation struct {
    ProcessId uint32
    Reserved  uint32
    StdInput  syscall.Handle
    StdOutput syscall.Handle
    StdError  syscall.Handle
}
```

As result I want to have an working syscall to obtain disk usage and disk space.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get total size of a drive in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54664751/how-to-get-total-size-of-a-drive-in-windows/54666920#54666920).

Comment: Your link is a good point, found similar code so far, thank you. To clarify my question. I want to get the system call for obtaining the disk usage to be generated like the function prototypes from above, to integrate it into the existing codebase.

Answer (score 0):

Create a file like this:

```
//go:generate mkwinsyscall -output zfree.go free.go
//sys getDiskFreeSpace(directoryName string, availableToCaller *int, numberOfBytes *int, numberOfFreeBytes *int) (err error) = GetDiskFreeSpaceExW
package main

func main() {
   var availableToCaller, numberOfBytes, numberOfFreeBytes int
   getDiskFreeSpace(
      `C:\`, &availableToCaller, &numberOfBytes, &numberOfFreeBytes,
   )
   println("availableToCaller", availableToCaller)
   println("numberOfBytes", numberOfBytes)
   println("numberOfFreeBytes", numberOfFreeBytes)
}
```

Then build [1]:

```
go mod init free
go generate
go mod tidy
go build
```

Alternatively, you can use the premade wrapper [2], but I prefer mine, as you don't have to worry about the string conversion.

1. https://github.com/golang/sys/tree/master/windows/mkwinsyscall
2. https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/sys/windows#GetDiskFreeSpaceEx