# How do I get the amount of free disk space on windows without using the deprecated syscall package in Go?

Tags: go, system-calls

There are a few different threads on here that outline how to do this using syscall, but it has since been deprecated. I'm looking for a solution that uses `golang.org/x/sys/windows`

Comment: as in https://stackoverflow.com/a/60724929/6309 ?

Comment: seems like this [https://github.com/ricochet2200/go-disk-usage] (old and maintained) lib implements the above in go.