# golang: how to check if a write fails due to insufficient disk space

Tags: go, filesystems

If a go program return error with `Write()`, it returns something like this:

```
write failed(*fs.PathError): write mnt/test.dat: no space left on device
```

Is there anyway other than string matching for 'no space left on device', to know that a PathError is due to insufficient disk space?

Note: I am using Linux, and **not** caring about how it works on Windows.

Comment: related: [Get amount of free disk space](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20108520/10197418)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it may be sensitive to the OS you compile for but you can check if the error wraps `syscall.ENOSPC`.

```golang
_, err := file.Write(stuff)
if err != nil {
    if errors.Is(err, syscall.ENOSPC) {
        // There was no space left on the device
        return "get more space"
    }
    // something else is wrong
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is there anyway other than string matching for 'no space left on device', to know that a PathError is due to insufficient disk space?

No.

Comment: The accepted answer works on linux!

Comment: @xrfang Package syscall is not covered by the Go compatibility promise. If this type of hack is good enough for you now and in the future this is fine.