# C Linux Check free space in mount

Tags: c, linux, mount

When I running `df -h` I can see that in `/dev` I use 6M and the size is 40M , and Available size is 34M .

How can I get this information with c code?

Comment: Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3992171/how-do-i-programmatically-get-the-free-disk-space-for-a-directory-in-linux

Comment: You could inspect the original code: [df.c](https://github.com/coreutils/coreutils/blob/master/src/df.c)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [here](https://www.systutorials.com/136585/how-to-get-available-filesystem-space-on-linux-a-c-function-and-a-cpp-example/):

Use the `statvfs` API:

```
// header for statvfs
#include <sys/statvfs.h>
```

and the prototype of the `statvfs` is

```
int statvfs(const char *path, struct statvfs *buf);
```

The results will be filled to the buf `statvfs` struct:

```
struct statvfs {
    unsigned long  f_bsize;    /* filesystem block size */
    unsigned long  f_frsize;   /* fragment size */
    fsblkcnt_t     f_blocks;   /* size of fs in f_frsize units */
    fsblkcnt_t     f_bfree;    /* # free blocks */
    fsblkcnt_t     f_bavail;   /* # free blocks for unprivileged users */
    fsfilcnt_t     f_files;    /* # inodes */
    fsfilcnt_t     f_ffree;    /* # free inodes */
    fsfilcnt_t     f_favail;   /* # free inodes for unprivileged users */
    unsigned long  f_fsid;     /* filesystem ID */
    unsigned long  f_flag;     /* mount flags */
    unsigned long  f_namemax;  /* maximum filename length */
};
```

The return type is:

> On success, zero is returned.  On error, -1 is returned, and errno is
>   set appropriately.

Also have a look at the [man3](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/statvfs.3.html) manpage of the `statvfs` command for more and detailed information.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked the [source of df from Coreutils](https://github.com/coreutils/coreutils/blob/master/src/df.c)?

It uses `statvfs()` from [`sys/statvfs.h`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/sys/statvfs.h.html) on Linux as well as on other POSIX-like systems.