# Is there a c api POSIX that calculte the free space on a disk

Tags: c++, c, linux, c++14, posix

I have a process that generate files in folder.
to avoid a possible crash, i have another process to calculte the size of this folder when a new file added (using inotify_add_watch) then i calculte the free size (my disk size less the folder size ),  in order to check if i should delete the old files.

The probleme in my solution that this disque can be used with another process/user, so the free space is not reliable .

My question : is there a better way to do it, like a linux api, which gave me the space still available on a disk?

Comment: Check man statvfs

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3992171/how-do-i-programmatically-get-the-free-disk-space-for-a-directory-in-linux

Answer (score 2):

The API you're looking for is [`statvfs`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/statvfs):

```
#include <sys/statvfs.h>

int statvfs(const char *path, struct statvfs *buf);
```

where `path` can be any path in the filesystem (in your case, you can use your results folder).

---

A very handy method for learning how to use such APIs in real code is to look at the source of existing tools like `df`.

Run `apt source coreutils` to get the source code - and have a look at the `src/df.c`. It makes usage of the function `get_fs_usage` in `lib/fsusage.c` - which calls `statvfs`.